# if i have a value in database field as 10 then i want to show 10 images in php

Tags: php, mysql

if i have a value in database field as 10 then i want to show 10 images or numbers like this (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ).  if i have a value in database field as 12 then i want to show 10 images or numbers like this (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ).

i am new to php so i didn't get any idea please help me.. i have written code like this.....

```
 $sql = "select * from hajj_umrah_package";

        $res = mysql_query($sql, $conn); 

        if( mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {

            $m = $row['available'];


        echo '<div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="panel panel-primary"> 
           <div class="panel-heading"> 
            <h3 class="panel-title">'.$row["package_title"].'</h3> 
           </div> 
          <div class="panel-body um-body"> <span style="color:#333;">'.$row["package_dsp"].'</span> <br> <br>
                 <span>'.$m++.'</span>



           </div> 

         </div>
        </div>';
        }
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want the number of images or numbers as listed in the database field?

Comment: `if i have a value in database field as 12 then i want to show 10 images or numbers like this (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ).` Wat?!? __10 !== 12__, or at least it wasn't back when I went to school

Comment: @MarkBaker hah! probably a typo

Comment: it's called "pagination", you should Google that ;-)

Comment: @user5173426 - and there was me thinking it was some of that "modern mathematics" I keep hearing about from teachers, either that or a base conversion

Comment: create a for loop in php `for $i=1; $i <=$m; $i++` within the for `echo $i` or `echo <img src="imgpath.jpg">`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your advise

Answer (score 0):

If you query to get `$m` works correct, you can use a for loop:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$m; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    echo "<img src='imgpath.png'>"
}
```

You can learn more about for loops in the php manual: http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.for.php

If you want to parameterize the path of your image, use this:

```
echo "<img src='imgpath". $i . ".png'>"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried this but in my database the available field contains the value 12 so the package_title and package_dsp also showing 12 times. I am new to php, so i couldn't make it perfect.

Comment: Then do not include it in the for loop.